# Showing the current intput/output rate on a cisco device

Tags: cisco, juniper, interface

Is there a way to check the current interface output/input rate on Cisco devices? the interface statistics only give the average over 5 minutes, and monitoring the interface seems to have a very long lag (as it also only shows the updated value over 5 minutes).

When I do a show interface on a Juniper device, it gives the current input/output rate.. is there a way to do this on a Cisco device?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An I/O rate must be over some time period since it is a number of bits per time period, just like your speed in a car is an average of the number of miles per hour. The Cisco device can change the time period for the average of a particular interface with the interface command, `load-interval`.

Your Juniper has to have a time period over which it averages the number of bits. It may be a one second time period, but you can't get bits per second unless you count the over a one second (or longer) time period.

Normally, you do want an I/O rate averaged over a time period longer than 1 second since it smooths out bursts and gives you a more accurate picture of throughput on an interface.

Comment: How do I use the `load-interval` command to show it over a second?

Comment: You can use the command to lower the interval. You could try 1 second, but, I believe, the minimum is 30 seconds. A one second interval really isn't useful information. Are you sure the Juniper uses a one second interval?

Comment: 30s is as low as it goes.

Comment: Well.. as soon as I start passing  traffic, the Juniper device shows the exact rate of traffic I am sending (In the `show interfaces` command).. It is very close to real time. The Cisco device on the other hand.. I have to wait around 7 minutes to get the exact amount of traffic being sent

Comment: Cisco also shows current traffic, but it is over a time period. For instance, if I set it to 30 seconds, all traffic from the last 30 seconds, including the traffic which pass as I was typing the command are included. The Juniper also gives you the same sort of thing, but I don't know over what time period it uses. I'm not sure what you are trying to get.

Comment: When I stop traffic passing on a juniper device, it takes ~ a second for the interface statistics on the juniper device to show 0 traffic being passed. On a cisco device.. it takes ~ 5 minutes for the traffic to go down to 0 (which makes sense since it is averaging it). What I am trying to achieve is to see current traffic (per second) on a cisco device. I guess cisco does not have that feature then.

Comment: Cisco _does_ have the current traffic rate, the same way Juniper does. You can set over what time period it checks for. I don't know what time period Juniper uses, but a bit rate, by definition, is the number of bits over a period of time. With Cisco, you can set that to a known time period (default is 5 minutes, but you can drop it as low as 30 seconds), and that may be true for Juniper, but you don't seem to know the time period. A 1 second period isn't really useful information, which is why the default for Cisco is 5 minutes.

Comment: From seeing how instantaneously the interface statistics detect changes in traffic, I see that the juniper device does change it on a real-time-basis (close to a second possibly). While I guess it is a minimum of 30 seconds as you say for cisco. Basically, when I pass traffic through a juniper device I CAN SEE ALL THE TRAFFIC WITHIN A SECOND OF STARTING IT, where as I cannot see this for a cisco device. Which is my initiial question, but as you said. cisco can only do a minimum of 30 seconds. How do I modify the command to change the interval? Will test some more and report back

Comment: What I'm saying is that the Cisco does give you the traffic within the last second. It is contained within what it reports for the last time period, which you can change down to 30 seconds using the interface command `load-interval`. You asked how to do this before, and I told you to use the interface command `load-interval`. It is really very simple.